# jsoup won't extract email only website

Tags: java, android, jsoup

I am having trouble with jsoup. It only is extracting website links not the email link. Here is my code:

```
try {
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url2).get();

            Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");

            for (Element web: links) {

                Log.i("websites/emails/etc.", web.attr("abs:href"));
            }

            Elements links2 = doc.select("link[href]");

            for (Element web: links2) {

                Log.i("websites/emails/etc.", web.attr("abs:href"));
            }
```

The logcat is only showing the website links.
Here is the inspected page:
[image: website inspected]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit --

I missed you were using Android.  I tested on the JVM and your code looked good, I re-tested on Android and see the same thing.  The solution appears to be remove the `abs:` qualifier from your `attr` call.

```
   Log.i("websites/emails/etc.", web.attr("href"));
```

Original answer, which may apply to other attempts to extract `mailto:`.

This is almost certainly the intended behavior from the website creator.  Due to the `mailto:` tags being easily scraped by spambot email harvesters, there are a variety of techniques used to make the `mailto:` tag not-obvious when you pull the raw HTML.  Instead, they cleverly encoded, or are generated dynamically by javascript. [See here for an example](http://www.albionresearch.com/misc/obfuscator.php).  Safari is showing you the element because these technique are designed to be correct in the browser, even when the just the HTML looks funky.  If you download with file with `curl` and look at the raw text, there is likely no "mailto:" tag there.

Comment: Thanks but how can I extract it?

Comment: That all depends on how it is encoded/obfuscated.  Pull the raw HTML and take a look at how they are obfuscating it and try work back from there.  The issue you have is the website is deliberately trying make this hard for you to do -- they don't want scripts to easily scape the email without a little work.

Comment: What about the =$0 at the end? Is this in jsoup's cookbook because I can't seem to find a way to extract it?

Comment: Huh.  I just noticed there is enough info in that screen cap to find the page you are looking at.  The `mailto:`'s are not encoded. Your code above is extracting them just fine on Jsoup 1.8.3 for me.

Comment: Really?! Thank you. Will try.

Comment: @TaylorCourtney I was testing on the JVM, I tested again an reproduced your error, see edit above for a solution